# How to get WeekDayName based on date

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic

I am busy learning ASP. I cant find any good documentation (As good as the PHP docs).

So This is what I am trying to do:

pseudo code:

```
dayname = WeekDayName(daynumberfromdate(31-1-2013))
```

I cant find a function that can do this.

Comment: Why am I downvoted!? Is asking for a function in a language I don't know so wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
days = Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday")
today = Date()
dayNumber = DatePart("w", today)
dayOfWeek = days(dayNumber - 1)
```

For more information on the `DatePart` function see:

> [DatePart Function (MSDN Library)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4kt42529%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

You can find the full documentation for VBScript (as used by Classic ASP) here:

> [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0aew7h6(v=vs.84).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0aew7h6%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

It's fairly comprehensive.

Also the "Hey, Scripting Guy!" blog on Technet has a trove of old articles covering VBScript tips and tricks:

> http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy
>
> http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/tags/vbscript/

Answer (score 1):

```
dayname = WeekdayName(weekday(now()),True)
```

'or

```
dayname = WeekdayName(weekday(now()))
```

1st returns "Wed", 2nd returns "Wednesday"